# Confused by derivation of variance swap payoff

Tags: itos-lemma, sde

I'm trying to follow
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance_swap#Pricing_and_valuation

where it seems to me that they're just subtracting a simple return:
$$ R_t = \frac{\mathrm{d}S_t}{S_t} = \mu \mathrm{d}t + \sigma \mathrm{d}Z_t $$

from the log return:
$$ r_t = \mathrm{d}(\mathrm{log} S_t) = \left(\mu - \frac{\sigma^2}{2} \right) \mathrm{d}t + \sigma \mathrm{d}Z_t $$

to get

$$ R_t - r_t = \frac{\mathrm{d}S_t}{S_t} - \mathrm{d}(\mathrm{log}S_t) = \frac{\sigma^2}{2}\mathrm{d}t $$

I'm obviously missing something obvious, but how can that difference depend on the volatility and/or elapsed time?  Isn't there a direct 1-to-1 mapping between simple and log returns ($ R_t = e^{r_t} - 1 $)?  Is there some implicit expected value that I'm missing?

Comment: Uh any reason for the multiple down votes?

Comment: Assume that there are two contracts, on with value $S_t$ and one with value $\log S_t$ (the "log contract" of Neuberger). Then by buying one and shorting the other you generate a P&L which depends on $\sigma^2$. Strictly speaking the "log contract" for S&P 500 does not exist, but it can be simulated https://quantlabs.net/academy/download/free_quant_instituitional_books_/[Journal%20of%20Portfolio%20Management,%20Neuberger]%20The%20Log%20Contract%20-%20A%20New%20Instrument%20to%20Hedge%20Volatility.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With integral definitions of $r_t$ and $R_t$, we do have:

$$ r_t := \int_0^t d(\ln S_u)  = \ln S_t - \ln S_0 \color{green}= \ln \left( \frac{S_t}{S_0}\right),$$

but:

$$ R_t := \int_0^t \frac{dS_u}{S_u} \color{red}{\not=} \frac{S_t - S_0}{S_0} \color{green}= {\rm e}^{r_t} -1. $$

In symbolic differentials language:

$$ \frac{dS_u}{S_u} \color{red}{\not=} \frac{dS_u}{S_0}. $$

Comment: Thank you!  So obvious now, but I don't think I would have caught that after any amount of staring at it.